# How to query a video in vimeo by title?

Tags: php, vimeo

How do I get a video matching a title name? We have php code that needs to pull video information for one or more videos by video title. Our video title have unique names. I'm new to Vimeo. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this documentation https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#search_videos and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332615/how-does-the-search-query-work-with-vimeo-api-for-my-videos-me-videos)

Answer (score 1):

To search your own videos, use `?query=foo` on the `/me/videos` endpoint. This should search both your video names as well as their descriptions (if they have descriptions).

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?query=foo
```

Make sure this request is made with a token authenticated to your own account with, at minimum, the scopes `public private`. Otherwise, the query will only return public videos.

Documentation for this endpoint is found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_videos

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to get videos matching a title using query. Couple of questions:

Comment: - Is there a way to pass multiple titles to the query in single call? I need to fetch all videos matching given set of titles.

- The returned json has lots of data (over 400 properties). Is there a way to get subset of properties?

Comment: @user12394911 Use the `fields` parameter to only return the metadata needed in your application, such as `name`, `uri`, `link`, etc. Documentation here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter